# Thermal Loss calculation of IGBT

Tags: power-electronics, datasheet, igbt, loss, switching-losses

I want to compute losses of an IGBT using datasheet information given by manufacturer. I want to calculate losses at 90 °C junction temperature while the information provided on datasheet is only for 25 °C and 175 °C of junction temperature.

Could anyone here please guide me how to calculate the approximately losses for 90 °C?

Comment: Depends on the type of losses. Some things are exponential in temperature (leakage), some things are linear (collector-emitter on voltage at high currents), some things actually decrease with temperature (collector-emitter on voltage at low currents), and some don't significantly change with temperature at all (parasitic capacitances).

Comment: I want to calculate total switching losses which includes losses in IGBT and losses in body diode during reverse recovery

Comment: Try asking the IGBT manufacturer if they have specifications for 90degC operation.  Better than guessing.

Comment: Can you specify which IGBT is it?  Perhaps providing  a datasheet would be better.

Comment: Linear interpolation between the 25 and 175 degree values?

Comment: RGS50TSX2DHR from ROHM